Load multiple GLB models into APS Viewer
Is it possible to use viewer.loadDocumentNode to load multiple models in GLB file format into the APS viewer or is there another way?
Self contained example of what I'm trying to do follows
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Multiple 3D Viewer - Autodesk Forge AggregatedView</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="viewer"></div>

    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js"></script>

    <script>
        function launchViewer( models ) {
          if( !models || models.length <= 0 )
            return console.error( 'Empty model input' );

          const options = {
            env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
            getAccessToken: null,
          };

          const options3d = {
            viewerConfig: {
              disableBimWalkInfoIcon: true
            }
          };

          Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer( options, function() {
            //get the viewer div
            const viewerDiv = document.getElementById( 'viewer' );

            //initialize the viewer object
            viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv);
            viewer.start();
            models.map((m)=>{
                Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(m, (doc) => {
                    var viewables = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
                    viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables,{
                        keepCurrentModels: true,
                        preserveView: true,  // 2D drawings
                        modelSpace: true,    // 2D drawings
                        applyRefPoint: true, // 3D shared coordinates
                        applyScaling: 'm',   // force all models to same scale
                        globalOffset: {x:0,y:0,z:0},  // force all models to origin
                        placementTransform: (new THREE.Matrix4()).setPosition(m.xform)
                    })
                    .then( console.info );
                });
            });
          });
        }

        const models = [
          'models/m1.glb',
          'models/m2.glb',
        ];

        launchViewer( models );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

When saving the code as index.html and opening it up in web browser, the following error occurs in web browser's console
Document.js:56 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'traverse')
    at new Document (Document.js:56:18)
    at Function.onSuccess (Document.js:174:29)
    at onSuccessWrapped (Xhr.js:587:40)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (Xhr.js:829:34)

Running the page on a static web server does not make any difference.

The loadDocumentNode function is used to load a document from SVF or SVF2 file format.
There is a glTF extension that you can use to load your GLB into the viewer without any previous file conversion.
Here's an article that describes how to load glTF into the APS viewer: glTF 2.0 Support in Forge Viewer.

Right, as far as I'm aware from all these scattered and possibly even outdated blog posts. viewer.loadModel() does not give the ability to load multiple models? There is no setting like keepCurrentModels: true as in the code in question.

You don't need this option to load multiple models. With viewer.loadModel(), the previous loaded models are not removed.

You might be right. I'm using viewer.loadModel() to insert about eighty SVF files to the viewer and it works fine for SVFs, but for GLBs converted from those SVFs what viewer.loadModel() does is a total disaster, so I was hoping viewer.loadDocumentNode() would be the right way to do it, but anyways I'm looking for alternative. Thanks.

@AlexAR is correct. Please use the glTF extension and viewer.loadModel() instead for glTF. The Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load is actually loading the manifest content from Model Derivative API's GET /{urn}/manifest, and parse it to Document object, so that we can load the model from the document object, and then use  viewer.loadDocumentNode() to load the model. When loading native file formats, there is no such info, so you cannot use it that way.
